# Accessing App cache, Python for Android - Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

Im wondering how to view files in the directory:

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[app name]/cache

I am using

```
from android import mActivity
```

and

```
context = mActivity.getApplicationContext()
result =  context.getExternalCacheDir()
App.get_running_app().root.pathlabel.text = str(result.toString())
```

to collect the string and display it for reference.

Ive connected the phone to my pc, with many apps having folders in the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ directory, but none for my app: org.test.kivycamerafive.

Is this file hidden in some way? Or does the function return this string without the directory existing? Wondering if I can view it easily while im debugging.

Storage Permissions:

main.py:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

request_permissions([
    Permission.CAMERA,
    Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
])
```

buildozer.spec:

```
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET,android.permission.CAMERA,android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Did you add the read and write storage permissions

Comment: Yes, question edited to reflect. Although a folder in this directory should be created when the app was installed? and it shouldn't affect its availability when accessing manually through USB?

Comment: Have you tried os.listdir on that path?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os.listdir` to view the files in the cache directory

```py
from android.activity import _activity as activity
from os import listdir

context = activity.getApplicationContext()
result =  context.getExternalCacheDir()

print(listdir(result.toString()))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: The return of the above is `/storage/emulated/0`

Comment: Did you write the code exactly as I wrote it above?